# validation logic for max measurement

Tags: javascript, typescript

We have 3 textboxes which accept length, width and height

Either length or width or height cannot be greater than 50

Either length or width or height cannot be greater than 45

Either length or width or height cannot be greater than 65

So there can be below combination

45 * 50 * 65

50 * 45 * 65

65* 45 * 50

I am writing logic in typescript but cannot find way.

```
 if (txtWidth.val() > 45 && txtLength.val() < 65 && txtHeight.val() < 50)
    string error = "you exceeded measurement"
```

the logic is not complete but i need good way to solve this or any hit would help

Comment: If I didn't know better  I'd think you were trying to get answers to your homework

Comment: @Scrimothy its not any homework. its actual logic in my real live project. Dont go on wrong syntax of code. I know syntax can be wrong in code sample i posted

Answer (score 1):

You could take the three measures, sort them after size, then apply the condition:

```
 const sizes: number[] = [width, height, length].sort();
 if(sizes[0] >= 45 || sizes[1] >= 50 || sizes[2] >= 65)
   alert("incorrect");
```

---

Alternatively you each value against all ranges, like:

```
 const check = (v: number) => +(v < 45) + +(v < 50) + +(v < 65);
```

That will return 3 if the passed value is lower than all ranges, 2 if it is bigger than 45, 1 if bigger than 50 and 0 if bigger than 65.

Then the multiple of all checks has to be bigger or equal 6 (3 * 2 * 1)

```
 if(check(width) * check(height) * check(length) < 6)
   alert("invalid");
```

Comment: can you tell how you declare constant in typescript as that gives error

Comment: i tried to convert constant check in typescript like var check = function (v) { return (v < 45) + (v < 50) + (v < 65); };  but still throws error

Comment: @james you should try to understand the error message before you are guessing into the wild.

Comment: typescript probably doesn't like that you're implicitly using a boolean as a number with your expression. You may have to cast them to numbers before you can add them together

Comment: @Scrimothy can you give me example of cast?

Comment: The DRY way would be like this, `boolToNumber(bool) { return bool ? 1 : 0 }` then `boolToNumber(v < 45)`, but you could also add the ternary for each statement

Comment: @scrimothy the DRY would actually be `+(v < 45)`

Comment: @JonasWilms can you update answer code with typescript format please?

Comment: @james sure, please decide for the language *before asking the question* the next time :)

Comment: @JonasWilms  i am sorry for it. But i also want to learn about this syntax you wrote. Can you please send me link to understand that syntax. I didnt understood much how that constant is declared. I will be greatful

Comment: what happens if one or two parameters are undefined

Comment: also looks like syntax is not correct for constant check you declared. it will be nice if you change all code written in answer in typescript

Comment: the output is not correct either. it always returns 0 if i pass for example 46 * 51 * 66.
so it outputs to 0 and then its not greater than 6 and then it will not throw alert

Comment: @james whoops, the condition must be inverted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190021/discussion-between-james-and-jonas-wilms).

Comment: this returns as valid 25 * 25 * 8

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a more succinct way to do this, but I'm thinking that you'd loop through each dimension and match it against your 3 maxes. I'm removing the lowest one that matches first so that you have more room for other dimensions that could be less than more than one max.

```js
function validateVolume(...args) {
  const maxes = [45, 50, 65];
  
  return args.every((dimension) => {
    if (dimension === null || dimension === undefined) {
      return false;
    }
    return maxes.some((max, index) => {
      const match = dimension <= max;
      if (match) {
        maxes.splice(index, 1);
      }
      
      return match;
    });
  });
}
console.log(validateVolume(undefined, 65, 50));
console.log(validateVolume(45, 65, 50));
console.log(validateVolume(45, 50, 65));
console.log(validateVolume(46, 50, 65));
```

Comment: i changed language to typescript in question

Comment: @James you should be able to use the same function above with typescript. Just change function definition to `validateVolume(...args: [number, number, number]): boolean`

Comment: what happens if other two parameters are undefined. this test fails console.log(validateVolume(45, undefined, 65))

Comment: @James yes, that was happy path only. I've updated my snippet to validate against undefined and null.